# MongoVue and Boolean

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to know how to insert a boolean with MongoVue tool.

I tried

```
{
  "IsGlobal": True,
}
```

// error when clicking insert button

and

```
{
  "IsGlobal": "True",
}
```

// it becomes a string

and

```
{
    "IsGlobal": new Boolean("True"),
}
```

// I get "Unable to parse Json: new Boolean..."

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks guys !

Comment: I found the answer, it's:

    {
      "IsGlobal": true, 
    }

Comment: You can post it as answer and accept.

Comment: Yeah sure, I wanted to post an answer but got an error from stackoverflow saying that I have to have at least 100 reputation to post an answer. Otherwise, I had to wait 8hours or something like that to post my answer. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer, is

```
{ 
    "IsGlobal": true, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While inserting you need to make sure you are using proper boolean keywords like (**true,false**).It should always start from lower case not from capital case.

> db.UserCredential.insert({"flag":true})
>   WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>   db.UserCredential.insert({"flag":false})
>   WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })